# Why does Entity Framework create a property with an appended number in a stored procedure, MyProp and MyProp1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

My stored procedure returns various columns, it is not variable, the results are always fixed.

When I press 'Get column information' in Entity Framework, the columns all correctly appear in the preview window, including `MyProp`.

When I press create complex type however, it ends up with

```
string MyProp {get; set;}
string MyProp1 {get; set;}
```

amongst all of the other fields in the complex type class.

Is there a reason this is happening? There shouldn't be a MyProp1. The rest of the columns are all fine.

ETA:

Nothing unusual in the edmx. Multiple things are returned in the sproc which are also of the same type (`nvarchar(30)`). The edmx is formatted identically for these as well as MyProp.  I can't see any clashes such as having a class with the same name as the property or anything like that.

I've blanked the field names, but `MyProp` is one of the fields that is detected just like the rest, it only appears once, no name clashes etc yet the output .cs file has it twice as `MyProp` and `MyProp1`

[image: Pic]

Comment: Entity has a mapping file that is used to associate the columns in the database with properties in your c# classes.  The mapping file has the extra column.  My question is what do you mean by complex type?  Is it another class or do you mean a number with a real and imaginary value.  If it is a number then why is the property declared as a string?

Comment: Yep, the edmx is showing `<ScalarProperty Name="MyProp" ColumnName="MyProp" />` the same as the other columns. The complex type part is within the EF designer, I will put a screenshot in.

Comment: I think you need to open the Entiry Designer (see : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/designer/data-types/complex-types) and compare the designer fields to the database fields to see if they match.

Answer (score 0):

Tearing my hair out for a while, I have fixed it.

The type of the column is `nvarchar(30) null`

In the sproc, I am populating it from a table in which the field is `nvarchar(20) null`, basically my sproc is this code (simplified, might not be 100% accurate):

```
DECLARE @Results TABLE (
    [MyProp] [nvarchar](30) Null
)

Insert Into @Results
    Select [MyProp] from MyTable

SELECT * From @Results
```

In `MyTable`, `MyProp` is actually `nvarchar(20) Null` rather than `nvarchar(30) Null`.

So even though there is no loss of precision, because it's smaller, for some reason EF seems to be examining how the table is populated and creating an extra field. I have no idea why, but changing MyProp to be `nvarchar(20) Null` to match the table it's being populated from has fixed it.

Baffling.